# When submit form use text from SELECT instead of value

Tags: jquery, html

There is a JQuery plugin I am using that shows a list of countries and states, its select option tag is like this:

```
<option value='US'>United States</option>
```

and when I submit it, I want it to POST(no ajax) "United States" instead of "US" - but I cannot find a good solution online ... anyone has any ideas?

PS. This is the plugin : http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/state/

PS. Final Solution:

- I just pass the ISO code back to PHP and use geoip to find the state/province/prefecture name
- Country is a bit more tricky, but I downloaded a json containing ISO 2digit code to country name, and use PHP to parse it

Comment: Please add your complete code or your plugin details.

Comment: To achieve this I'd add a hidden input to the form which is updated with the chosen option's text when a selection is made - assuming you need both the short value and the full country name to be sent

Comment: Which jQuery plugin? There are quite a few out there

Comment: http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/state/ <== this is the plugin

Comment: @SirGalahad add the plugin link to the question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this has been tagged as JQuery, here's a JQuery solution... you can retrieve the inner text of an option element by using

```
$("#list option:selected").text();
```

as well as

```
$("#list option[value='US']").text()
```

As you have not addressed the issue fully, if you are doing a POST request to the server using a form, you can create a hidden input on the form, and when values are changed you can append the results of that to the hidden field using the above code.

Edit: To make it 'automatic':

```
$("#list").change(function(){
   // Set the hidden field here with selected option
})
```

Edit: It appears the plugin also has a change event which relies on JQuery (why? I don't know..)

```
$('#list').on('change.bfhselectbox', function () {
   // Set the hidden field here too if you wish...
});
```

Comment: thank you ... i know how to retrieve that, but the problem is to make it automatic ... umm, I will use hidden field then

Comment: @SirGalahad See my edit for option change listener, in there you retrieve the value and set it in the hidden field 'automatically', and by that I mean every time the value changes.